# DiscordJS Embed Fields imported from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am attempting to import fields of an embed in a file named fields.js where it contains

```js
const myFields = [
{name: 'something', value: 'something'},
{name: 'something', value: 'something'},
{name: 'something', value: 'something'},
];

module.exports.myFields = myFields;
```

then in my commandfile.js I am trying to call it like so

```js
const myFields = require('../fields');

const embedTest = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#4278f5')
.setTitle('__**MY TITLE**__')
.setThumbnail('mylink.com')
.setDescription(`**something**`)
.addFields([myFields])
.setFooter({text:`my footer`});
```

I am getting RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_NAME]: MessageEmbed field names must be non-empty strings

Comment: I think you need to use `${myFields}` instead of `[myFields]`

Comment: @新Acesyyy I have tried that and it returns same error

Comment: I think its not going to work i you going to create like these, using `[]` make it as `array`

Comment: .addFields(myFields) remove the variable from an array because it is already set as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation, read:

In `fields.js` you exported myFields as *part* of the `module.exports` object, not as the default export:

```js
module.exports.myFields = myFields;
```

This means you are exporting an object which looks like:

```js
{
  myFields: //... etc
}
```

However, you have imported `myFields` like this:

```js
const myFields = require('../fields');
```

Which basically means you are doing this:

```js
const embedTest = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#4278f5')
.setTitle('__**MY TITLE**__')
.setThumbnail('mylink.com')
.setDescription(`**something**`)
.addFields([{
  myFields: [
    //... your fields
  ]
}])
.setFooter({text:`my footer`});
```

## Solution

Change the export statement to:

```js
module.exports = myFields;
```

This sets the myFields array to the default export, rather than enclosing it in an object.

Then you have TWO options. Pick one not both:

### 1.

Use `...` (spread operator) to "spread" the array out. Edit `commandfile.js`

```js
const myFields = require('../fields');

const embedTest = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#4278f5')
.setTitle('__**MY TITLE**__')
.setThumbnail('mylink.com')
.setDescription(`**something**`)
.addFields([...myFields]) // ADD 3 DOTS (spread operator)
.setFooter({text:`my footer`});
```

### 2. Recommended

Simply remove the `[]` surrounding myFields as myFields is the array

```js
const myFields = require('../fields');

const embedTest = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#4278f5')
.setTitle('__**MY TITLE**__')
.setThumbnail('mylink.com')
.setDescription(`**something**`)
.addFields(myFields) // removed []
.setFooter({text:`my footer`});
```